# Entity Framework 4: Adding dervied entity won't show in count until save

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-4

I have an "Investment" entity that is derived from "BaseEntity".
If I create and add a new "Investment" like so:

```
investment = new Investment();
investment.Name = "Investment 01";
_context.BaseEntities.AddObject(entity);
```

and query the count (before saving changes)

```
_context.BaseEntities.OfType<Investment>().Count();
```

it returns zero. The same line returns 1 after _context.SaveChanges();

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing anything wrong. This is how EF works. No changes are done in database until you execute `SaveChanges` - it is called unit of work. You prepare all changes in memory and then save them all together in one transaction.

Comment: I now that. But my understanding is, that the DataContext should give me the right Count because it has new newly added object in memory. If I do: _container.BaseEntities.Count() I get the right number.

Comment: I would like to have an ObjectSet of "Investment" rather than an "ObjectQuery".

Answer (score 0):

An entity which is still in insert state will not be included in query results since the object has not been persisted with the `SaveChanges()`

Executing the `_context.BaseEntities.OfType<Investment>().Count();` method will make a request to the SQL server and return the results found in the database.

When using the `GetObjectByKey` method, a way to fetch the entity from the context instance if it was previously loaded,which is found on the `ObjectContext`, will also react the same way. Since the object is in new / insert state, the context will treat it as non existant until the save.

Edit:

In the code in the question you are using _context and in the comment you are mentioning 
_container.BaseEntities.Count()

what is the difference between these two objects ?

Comment: So why can't I get an ObjectSet of "Investment"? I actually don't want to work with the ObjectQuery.

Comment: why not work with an in-memory list and then commit to the context ?

Comment: It would be possible to do that... But why bother. I can't understand why EF has to handle derived entities that different.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behavior as the object is sitting in the state manager until you call SaveChanges(). Only after you call SaveChanges() will the object become available in your count.