# Entity Framework 4: Why can't I get an ObjectSet of derived entities rather than an ObjectQuery?

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-4

I have an "Investment" entity that is derived from "BaseEntity".

With `_container.BaseEntities.OfType<Investment>()` I get an ObjectQuery that always queries the database.

Therefore I would rather have an `ObjectSet<Investment>`.

I can't understand why EF doesn't support this for derived entities... Or does it? ;)

If I would go ahead and create a "root entity" in EF (which would be silly) that has associations to all my derived entities, I would get EntityCollections for those entities through the navigation properties of that one root-entity. But there must be another way...

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

That is how it works in EF ObjectContext API. If you try to create `ObjectSet` for derived entity you will get:

> ArgumentException: There are no
>   EntitySets defined for the specified
>   entity type 'Investment'. If
>   'Investment' is a derived type, use
>   the base type instead. Parameter name:
>   TEntity

Also once you define inheritance there are no navigation properties to derived entities. The association which offers navigation property is changed to inheritance.

I also followed your [former questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715462/entity-framework-4-adding-dervied-entity-wont-show-in-count-until-save) which is probably source of this one and I have to say I tried a lot but I can never get your behavior. Even if I call Count directly to `ObjectSet` I always get SQL query (checked in the profiler) and count of entities in the database - not in the set.

Comment: Hi, if I have a navigation property "Reports" on an "Investment" and Report is also derived from "BaseEntity", this navigation property returns an EntityCollection<Report>. This is fine. I might have confused ObhectSet and EntityCollection in regards of "Count()" on the cached entities. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectQuery<T>` does not always query the database. It is only a *query specification* - in this case a specification to return all BaseEntities of type `Investment`. You can compose it with additional filters or orderby clauses or projections and so on. Nothing is executed in the database until you apply some greedy operator like `ToList()` or `First()` etc. or until you apply a foreach loop to fetch the results.

Comment: I understand that! But a simple ObjectSet like you have for non inherited entities let's you add objects and keeps them in memory. If you add an "Investment" with _container.BaseEntities.AddObject(investment) and you do _container.BaseEntities.OfType<Investment>().ToList, the added "Investment" insn't in that list, because it's not saved to the database yet. Thus it would be much easier if I could have an ObjectSet<Investment> !

Comment: @SolarX: Sorry, then I misinterpreted the background of your question. Would `_container.BaseEntities.ToList()` return the added but not yet saved `Investment` entity? Anyway, you should edit this point into your question, it makes the reason behind the question clearer, and perhaps someone knows a workaround.

Comment: Not to worry :) EF jut made me a bit edgy today ;) Thank you very much for your assistance!