# How to get the Primary Key(s) in Entity Framework 4.1, i.e. using DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

The answers I'm seeing here are for ObjectContext. Is there a property to determine an entity's primary key names when using DbContext?

Ah.. one of those times that I wish Entity Framework is open source! I can glean this primary key name information from .Find method :-)

Comment: You can view the source code at http://entityframework.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You cannot use `DbContext` for that - DbContext API is just dumb wrapper with only most needed functionality. For everything more complex you must convert `DbContext` back to `ObjectContext` and use it. Try something like this:

Extract **key names**:

```
public static string[] GetEntityKeyNames<TEntity>(this DbContext context) where TEntity : class
{
  if (context == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

  var set = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
  var entitySet = set.EntitySet;
  return entitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(k => k.Name).ToArray();
}
```

Here's a method that will extract the **key values** of an entity:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> GetEntityKeys<TEntity>(this DbContext context, TEntity entity)
  where TEntity : class
{
  if (context == null)
    throw new NullReferenceException("context");

  var type = typeof(TEntity);

  var set = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
  var entitySet = set.EntitySet;
  var keys = entitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers;
  var props = keys.Select(k => type.GetProperty(k.Name));
  return props.Select(p => p.GetValue(entity));
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if TEntity is derived class. Is there a way to do this without CreateObjectSet<TEntity> ?

Comment: In case anyone else tries this (EF 6) and receives a message saying: The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter... it requires a `where TEntity : class` constraint. CreateObjectSet signature and def: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn236948%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

Comment: Should we dispose the created ObjectSet ?

Comment: @Guillaume, no, it's not an `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 4):

The [solution proposed by Ladislav Mrnka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6908874/143503) won't work for derived entities as [You can't create an object set for a derived type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715990/entity-framework-4-why-cant-i-get-an-objectset-of-derived-entities-rather-than). You'll see this error :

> ArgumentException: There are no EntitySets defined for the specified
>   entity type ... If ... is a derived type, use the
>   base type instead. Parameter name: TEntity

Here is my solution avoiding creating an object set :

```
public string[] GetEntityKeyNames<TEntity>(DbContext context)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    }
    var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext;
    //We must use the namespace of the context and the type name of the entity
    string entityTypeName = context.GetType().Namespace + '.' + typeof(TEntity).Name;
    var entityType = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItem<EntityType>(entityTypeName, DataSpace.CSpace);
    return entityType.KeyProperties.Select(k => k.Name).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get to ObjectContext because DbContext mostly wraps ObjectContext...

see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696590%28v=vs.103%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283139.aspx

Comment: I already know that (`(db as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext`), I'm trying to find out how to get the primary key names of an entity

Comment: Here's the old approach, it hits the database however http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958921/entity-framework-4-how-to-find-the-primary-key/2959046#2959046

Answer (score 1):

You could find primary key value from EntityKey class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitykey.aspx).

and you could find EntityKey object from DbContext like so :

```
ObjectContext context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
EntityKey key = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(model).EntityKey;
```

Comment: @agussyahpurta This will only work incase object state manager has state for the model object otherwise it will crash

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to make sure that I got the key. It is essentially the same as @Agus Syahputra 's answer with one important difference. I've added the entire answer below.

Note: I've tested this only on EF6 and I'm not sure if this works with earlier versions of EF.

```
//I'm currently inside savechanges of my dbcontext
//if you're typing this code outside your dbcontext, replace this with your dbcontext    
var objectStateEntry = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.Entity);
    string keyName = objectStateEntry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Key;
```